# Merge lists in Python by placing every nth item from one list and others from another?

Tags: python, list, python-2.7, merge

I have two lists, `list1` and `list2`.

Here **`len(list2) << len(list1)`**.

Now I want to merge both of the lists such that every **nth element** of final list is **from `list2`** and **the others from `list1`**.

For example:

```
list1 = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h']

list2 = ['x', 'y']

n = 3
```

Now the final list should be:

```
['a', 'b', 'x', 'c', 'd', 'y', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h']
```

What is the most [Pythonic](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Pythonic) way to achieve this?

I want to add all elements of `list2` to the final list, final list should include all elements from `list1` and `list2`.

Comment: I believe the output you posted here is for `n=2` not `n=3`, nop?

Comment: @IronFist I said 3rd element not index=3?

Comment: What constraints do you place on the size of list2? Are you cycling through list2 or only adding them to list1 until they are exhausted? This is not a clear problem.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Making the larger list an iterator makes it easy to take multiple elements for each element of the smaller list:

```
list1 = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h']
list2 = ['x', 'y'] 
n = 3

iter1 = iter(list1)
res = []
for x in list2:
    res.extend([next(iter1) for _ in range(n - 1)])
    res.append(x)
res.extend(iter1)

>>> res
['a', 'b', 'x', 'c', 'd', 'y', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h']
```

This avoids `insert` which can be expensive for large lists because each time the whole list needs to be re-created.

Comment: Just curious, any reason not to use `iter1.next()` and prefer `next(iter1)` over it?

Comment: Python 3. Always use `next(obj)` because it works with Python 2 **and** 3.

Answer (score 7):

To preserve the original list, you could try the following:

```
result = copy.deepcopy(list1)
index = n - 1
for elem in list2:
    result.insert(index, elem)
    index += n
```

result

```
['a', 'b', 'x', 'c', 'd', 'y', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h']
```

Answer (score 2):

Using the [`itertools` module](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html) and the supplementary [`more_itertools` package](https://pythonhosted.org/more-itertools/api.html), you can construct an iterable solution a couple different ways. First the imports:

```
import itertools as it, more_itertools as mt
```

This first one seems the cleanest, but it relies on `more_itertools.chunked()`.

```
it.chain(*mt.roundrobin(mt.chunked(list1, n-1), list2))
```

This one uses only `more_itertools.roundrobin()`, whose implementation is taken from the `itertools` documentation, so if you don't have access to `more_itertools` you can just copy it yourself.

```
mt.roundrobin(*([iter(list1)]*(n-1) + [list2]))
```

Alternatively, this does nearly the same thing as the first sample without using any `more_itertools`-specific functions. Basically, `grouper` can replace `chunked`, but it will add `None`s at the end in some cases, so I wrap it in `it.takewhile` to remove those. Naturally, if you are using this on lists which actually do contain `None`, it will stop once it reaches those elements, so be careful.

```
it.takewhile(lambda o: o is not None,
   it.chain(*mt.roundrobin(mt.grouper(n-1, list1), list2))
)
```

I tested these on Python 3.4, but I believe these code samples should also work in Python 2.7.

Comment: Replicating the list iterator and using `roundrobin` to advance each is clever.

Answer (score 1):

What about the below solution? However I don't have a better one...

```
>>> list1 = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h']
>>> list2 = ['x', 'y']
>>> n = 2
>>> for i in range(len(list2)):
...     list1.insert(n, list2[i])
...     n += 3
...     
... 
>>> list1
['a', 'b', 'x', 'c', 'd', 'y', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h']
```

`n` is 2 because the index of third element in a list is 2, since it starts at 0.

Answer (score 0):

```
list(list1[i-1-min((i-1)//n, len(list2))] if i % n or (i-1)//n >= len(list2) else list2[(i-1)//n] for i in range(1, len(list1)+len(list2)+1))
```

Definitely not pythonic, but I thought it might be fun to do it in a one-liner. More readable (really?) version:

```
list(
    list1[i-1-min((i-1)//n, len(list2))]
        if i % n or (i-1)//n >= len(list2)
        else
    list2[(i-1)//n]
        for i in range(1, len(list1)+len(list2)+1)
)
```

Basically, some tinkering around with indexes and determining which list and which index to take next element from.

Answer (score 0):

Yet another way, calculating the slice steps:

```
list1 = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h']
list2 = ['x', 'y'] 
n = 3

res = []
m = n - 1
start, end = 0, m
for x in list2:
    res.extend(list1[start:end])
    res.append(x)
    start, end = end, end + m
res.extend(list1[start:])

>>> res
['a', 'b', 'x', 'c', 'd', 'y', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h']
```

Answer (score 0):

```
list1 = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h']
list2 = ['x', 'y']
n = 3
new = list1[:]

for index, item in enumerate(list2):
    new[n * (index + 1) - 1: n * (index + 1) - 1] = item

print(new)
```

Answer (score 0):

I admire @David Z's use of `more_itertools`.  Updates to the tools can simplify the solution:

```
import more_itertools as mit

n = 3
groups = mit.windowed(list1, n-1, step=n-1)
list(mit.flatten(mit.interleave_longest(groups, list2)))
# ['a', 'b', 'x', 'c', 'd', 'y', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h']
```

Summary: `list2` is being interleaved into groups from `list1` and finally flattened into one list.

Notes

1. `groups`: `n-1` size sliding windows, e.g. `[('a', 'b'), ('c', 'd'), ('e', 'f'), ('g', 'h')]`
2. `interleave_longest` is presently equivalent to `roundrobin`
3. `None` is the default fillvalue.  Optionally remove with `filter(None, ...)`

Answer (score -1):

Maybe here is another solution, slice the `list1` the correct index then add the element of `list2` into `list1`.

```
>>> list1 = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h']
>>> list2 = ['x', 'y'] 
>>> n = 3
>>> for i in range(len(list2)):
...     list1 = list1[:n*(i+1) - 1] + list(list2[i]) + list1[n*(i+1)-1:]
... 
>>> list1
['a', 'b', 'x', 'c', 'd', 'y', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h']
```