# How To Make Every Fifth Post An Ad Post In Django

Tags: django, django-views, django-templates

I am trying to allow users to sponsor a post to bring more clicks to there posts. I want to make every fifth post a post that is a sponsored post but if i try to just use divisible by in the templates and loop through ads then it will post *all* of the ads after the fourth post

here is some code i have tried

EDIT:I have changed the question to something that won't show the posts can someone show me where i'm wrong?

models:

```
class Ads(models.Model):
    post = models.ForeignKey(Post, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
```

views:

```
def home(request, pk):
    
   post_list = []
   ad_list = []
   for p in Post.objects.all():
       post_list.append(p.Post) 
   for a in Ads.objects.all():
       ad_list.append(p.Ads) 
   n = 5
   iter1 = iter(post_list)
   post_ad_list = []
   for x in ad_list:
       post_ad_list.extend([next(iter1) for _ in range(n - 1)])
       post_ad_list.append(x)
   post_ad_list.extend(iter1)

   context = {
       'posts': post_ad_list,
   }
return render(request, 'new.html', context)
```

templates i have tried but don't work:

```
{% for item in posts %}

    //prints products and ads

   
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: This template tag will no doubt help you; https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/?from=olddocs#divisibleby

Comment: That template tag helps me do an ad every fifth post but i don't know how to make it post one ad out of the objects instead of posting all of them

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, so you could enumerate your `Post` queryset so that you can insert an ad every x objects. This would make for a verbose and easily understandable approach.

Or you could do something with `chain` from `itertools` a bit like this;

```
>>> N = 5  # element to insert ad
>>> k = 'Ad'  # Thing added to the list
>>>
>>> list(chain(*[letters[i : i+N] + [k] if len(letters[i : i+N]) == N else letters[i : i+N] for i in range(0, len(letters), N)]))
['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'Ad', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'Ad', 'k', 'l']
```

So as you can see there, an 'Ad' is added every 5 elements.

If you convert you two querysets into lists, you could do `ads.pop()` to insert the element into the list of posts.

Comment: Thank you, can you also tell me if i need to change from Ads.objects.all() because the posts from model Ads won't be printed out in the template for some reason and i think the reason is Ads.objects.all()

Comment: Well `Ads.objects.all()` will just give you all of your ads, so if you then don't see any ads it'd suggest you don't have any ads.

Comment: i have added them through the django admin but they won't show up. i thought that maybe i needed to do something like Ads.posts or someting

Comment: Well you could get the ads associated to a `Post` because you've got the FK, but if you're only showing an ad every 5 posts, it won't be ads associated with each post. It's really up to you how that works.

Comment: The problem here is that if you have multiple ads in the list, is going to show always the same ad(first one), is not going to take the second and on...

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming that you can use the same template code for both printing a post and an ad. Therefore, it is smart to not put too much logic into the template but rather shift that into the view.

Follow an approach like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34692738/merge-lists-in-python-by-placing-every-nth-item-from-one-list-and-others-from-an) to combine the two lists/querysets to your liking.

Then, show the elements of the combined list like that in your template (assuming the newly created list is called products_and_ads:

```
{% for item in products_and_ads %}
  {# print the stuff you want #}
{% endfor %}
```

You can of course now also add some sort of indicator that it is an ad (which you for sure should). But since this can be done in a variety of ways (included in the title, a boolean value, ...) that's up to you.

Comment: I tried something and added it to my question can you tell me where im wrong with appendin the objects to a list