# Django: How To Merge Two Object Lists With One List Appending To Every Fifth Element?

Tags: django, django-views

I am trying to make a list of posts where every fifth post is an ad post so i want to make a list where every fifth element is from the ad list.

i have tried something from this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/34692876/14790632

What am i doing wrong with assigning these object lists into one list

views.py:

```
def home(request, pk):

    #i tried this
    #post_list = []
    #ad_list = []
    #for p in Post.objects.all():
        #post_list.append(p.Post) 
    #for a in Ads.objects.all():
        #ad_list.append(p.Ads)

    #and i have tried this below
    post_list = Post.objects.all()
    ad_list =  Ads.objects.all()

    n = 5
    iter1 = iter(post_list)
    post_ad_list = []
    for x in ad_list:
        post_ad_list.extend([next(iter1) for _ in range(n - 1)])
        post_ad_list.append(x)
    post_ad_list.extend(iter1)

    context = {
        'posts': post_ad_list,
    }

    return render(request, 'new.html', context)
```

models.py:

```
class Ads(models.Model):
    post = models.ForeignKey(Post, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
```

EDIT: after implementing from the answers i am now getting the posts but not the ad posts. i think this is because i am using Ads.objects.all() but what should i change this to?

Comment: you can give your model ?

Comment: I have added it to the question

Comment: I want to ask if that is true,  You want to get an ad from id 5 ?

Comment: No i want the ad to be made every fifth element in the list so that when i print it in the template every fifth post will be an ad

Comment: Sorry I'm confused, what you mean is element or data ads?

Comment: i am trying to make posts which are ads that appear after every fourth post, so i need to make a list of all of the posts with each fifth item in the list being ad post. here is the answer i used to get to this point, it might help you understand https://stackoverflow.com/a/65685024/14790632

Comment: you only want get element 5 right ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are in the right direction, try this:

```
def home(request, pk):
    post_list = Post.objects.all()
    ad_list =  Ads.objects.all()

    offset = 4
    iter1 = iter(post_list)
    post_start = 0
    post_ad_list = []
    for x in ad_list:
        post_ad_list.extend(post_list[post_start:post_start + offset])
        post_ad_list.append(x)
        post_start += offset

    context = {
        'posts': post_ad_list,
    }

    return render(request, 'new.html', context)
```

Note that there is no need to add the posts again after the loop

Answer (score 1):

you can do this

```
def home(request, pk):

    #i tried this
    #post_list = []
    #ad_list = []
    #for p in Post.objects.all():
        #post_list.append(p.Post) 
    #for a in Ads.objects.all():
        #ad_list.append(p.Ads)

    #and i have tried this below
    post_list = Post.objects.all()
    ad_list =  Ads.objects.all()

    n = 5
    iter1 = iter(post_list)
    post_ad_list = []
    for x in ad_list:
        # you select one
        # this output only element 5
        post_ad_list.extend(post_list[4:5])
        post_ad_list.append(x)
        # or this if you using this => every 5 data will be retrieved => output: [5,10,15,20]
        for i in len(post_list):
            if not i % n:
                post_ad_list.extend(post_list[i-1:i])
        post_ad_list.append(x)

 
    context = {
        'posts': post_ad_list,
    }

    return render(request, 'new.html', context)
```